# Default logo according to theme setting

Tags: files

I'm creating the theme with two styles, dark and light. User can choose which style he wants in theme settings. My default theme logo is in the root of the theme.

Now I want to change default logo according to choosen style, so if the user choose dark style and doesn't set logo image, default logo is `logo.png` form theme root, but if user choose light style and doesn't set logo image, default logo is `logo_light.png` from theme root.

How can I override default logo according to result from `theme_get_setting`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner solution would be using your theme `hook_preprocess_page`, for example in a multi skin theme i have:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page( &$vars)
{
    //-> skin name, use default logo?, show logo?
    $skin = theme_get_setting("skin");
    $default_logo = theme_get_setting("default_logo");
    $toggle_logo = theme_get_setting("toggle_logo");

    $url = file_create_url(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme'));

    if( $default_logo && $toggle_logo)
        if( empty($skin)) $vars['logo'] = "$url/logo.png"; //default style logo
        else              $vars['logo'] = "$url/skins/$skin/logo.png";

}
```

then inside the page.tpl just the standard

```
<div id="header-logo">
   <?php if( $logo): ?>
      <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
   <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can by adding algorythm like this:

```
<div id="logo">
  <a href="<? print $front_page; ?>"><img src="<? if (theme_get_setting(theme)=="dark") print $logo; else print $logo_light; ?> border="0" alt="<? print $site_name; ?>"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but what happens when user set custom logo in theme settings and choose light style? probbably the user's logo won't render but my logo_light.png will...

Comment: you should give the link to your base theme to look the code. or give the archive of your theme as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it. I just check if the `default_logo` checkbox is checked. There is my code:

```
<div class="logo"><a class="logo-a" href="<?php print $base_url; ?>">
<img
<?php if(theme_get_setting('default_logo') == '1' && theme_get_setting('style') == 'light'): ?>
src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_theme'); ?>/logo_light.png"/></a>
<?php else: ?>
src="<?php print render($logo); ?>"/></a>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```